# Are signed measures badly defined?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, definition, signed-measures

I'm reading *Real Analysis - Modern Techniques and Their Applications* by Folland. On page 85, signed measures are defined as follows.

> Let $(X, \mathcal{M})$ be a measurable space. A **signed measure** on $(X, \mathcal{M})$ is a function $\nu : \mathcal{M} \rightarrow [-\infty,\infty]$ such that:
>
> 1. $\nu(\varnothing) = 0$;
> 2. $\nu$ assumes at most one of the values $\pm \infty$;
> 3. if $\{E_j\}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{M}$, then $\nu(\bigcup_1^\infty E_j) = \sum_1^\infty \nu(E_j)$, where the latter sum converges absolutely if $\nu(\bigcup_1^\infty E_j)$ is finite.

My issue is with the third condition. Specifically, what is it saying if $\nu(\bigcup_1^\infty E_j)$ is not finite? The summation might not even make sense, depending on the values of the $\nu(E_j)$ (e.g. if it is the alternating series $\sum (-1)^j$). Is this condition saying that the sum will always make sense? Or is it only saying the equality holds when the sum makes sense?

How can this condition be formulated correctly? And is there a textbook with a precise, rigorous formulation? (I couldn't find one.)

Comment: Someone will need to confirm this, but my guess is that it means: "if $\{E_j\}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{M}$, then $\nu(\bigcup_1^\infty E_j) = \sum_1^\infty \nu(E_j)$, **and** the latter sum converges absolutely if $\nu(\bigcup_1^\infty E_j)$ is finite."

Comment: It says the sum always makes sense (either as a finite or infinite-valued sum). If you somehow assigned values to sets in $\mathcal M$ for which such a sum did not make sense it wouldn't be a signed measure.

Comment: Actually, the second condition means ensures that if $\sum |\nu(E_j)| \to \infty$, then $|\nu(\bigcup E_j)| = \infty$, because the negative values can't compensate for the positive values, because there is only a finite negative mass. (this assuming that $\nu$ only assume $+\infty$, else replace by $-\nu$)

Comment: Absolute convergence follows from the fact that $\nu\left(\bigcup_1^\infty E_j\right)$ is independent of the order of the sets $E_j$, so if you actually have a signed measure, $\sum_1^\infty\nu(E_j)$ must also be independent of the order.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Good point. So in my comment above, the "and" part was redundant. Now I think that part 3) could have been stated simply as: " if $\{E_j\}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{M}$, then $\nu(\bigcup_1^\infty E_j) = \sum_1^\infty \nu(E_j)$." (But again someone should tell me if I'm understanding correctly or not.)

Comment: @littleO: That’s my understanding. The part about absolute convergence is an additional remark.

Comment: @littleO That doesn't really answer my question; the absolute convergence part is fine with me. What I'm asking is, what guarantees that $\sum_1^\infty \nu(E_j)$ is well-defined?

Comment: @Sambo Would it be more clear if part 3) were phrased as: "if $\{E_j\}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{M}$, then $\nu(\bigcup_1^\infty E_j) =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n \nu(E_j)$". When someone states that $a = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$, they are telling you that the infinite sum converges to $a$ (if $a$ is finite) or else diverges to $\infty$ (if $a = \infty$) or else diverges to $-\infty$ (if $a = -\infty$).

Comment: @littleO I see what you mean; that does help. I guess the reason writing the equality with the infinite sum doesn't immediately register as saying "this infinite sum exists" is that a lot of Calc 2 textbooks and classes will write things like "$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n$", and ask "does this converge?". I also think (though this could just be my own bias) that the fact that this sum always exists, even with sets of negative sign, is counter-intuitive enough that it is worthy of mention.

Comment: Also, it reminds me of thinks like: "$A = \sum_1^\infty (-1)^n$, so $A+A = 1$, so $\sum_1^\infty (-1)^n = A = 1/2$" (*shudder*)

Comment: The best way to state this would be to say that $\nu(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j)$ equals the **unconditional sum**
$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \nu(E_j)$, namely the limit of  the net $\big\{\sum_{j\in F} \nu(E_j)\big\}_{F\in \mathscr F({\mathbb N})}$, where $\mathscr
F({\mathbb N})$ is  the directed set formed by the
finite subsets of ${\mathbb N}$, under the order of inclusion.

Comment: The summation $\sum_1^\infty \nu(E_j)$ always make sense, because of **condition 2**: $\nu$ assumes at most one of the values $\pm \infty$. For instance, it cannot be the alternating series $\sum (-1)^j$.

Comment: @Ramiro But you're implicitly using condition 3 for series of the same sign, so that's a circular argument.

Comment: @Sambo There no circular argument at all. Series of the same sign either converge to a finite value or they converge to $\pm \infty$ ( depending on the sign of the terms).

Comment: @Ramiro Yes, but say your sequence of sets is $(E_k)_k$ where $\mu(E_k)$ is $1$ if $k$ is even and $-1$ if $k$ is odd. Then to show that $\mu(\bigcup E_{2k}) = \infty$ and $\mu(\bigcup E_{2k+1}) = -\infty$ (which is how I assume you're deriving your contradiction with condition 2), you need to apply condition 3.

Comment: @Sambo  Try to completely define a signed measure where you would have a sequence of set $ (E_k)_k$  where $\mu(E_k)$ is $1$ if $k$ is even and $−1$ if $k$ is odd.

Comment: @Sambo You are missing the main point. It is a definition! Not a deduction. In order to $\nu$ to satisfy the condition 3 of the **definition**, we must have $\nu(\bigcup_1^\infty E_j) = \sum_1^\infty \nu(E_j)$, which means that the right-hand summation must be defined.

Comment: @Sambo In Halmos' **Measure Theory**, Chapter VI $\S 28$, when defining signed measure, Halmos clealy explains: "*We observe that implicit in the requirement of countable additivity
is the requirement that if $\{E_n\}$ is a disjoint sequence of
measurable sets, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E_n)$ is either convergent
or definitely divergent (to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$) --- in any case that symbol $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E_n)$ makes sense*".